# How can I create an MRE that involves multiple files?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, minimal-reproducible-example

MREs are great, but often it takes more than one isolated piece of code to reproduce an issue. It seems the in-built MRE tool (the one with the "Run this code snippet" button) can only do so much when it is the case.

How can I create an MRE that involves multiple interconnected files? Is referencing [CodePen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CodePen) and similar sites acceptable in these kinds of situations (though, I'm not sure CodePen is helpful with backend projects)? It can involve interactions with databases too which complicates it even further. Can I get away with not including runnable MREs in such cases?

Comment: Part of providing a MRE would be to reduce the MRE to the simplest instance. I would not consider a MRE that spans multiple files to be a MRE.

Comment: @SecurityHound but it may still be multiple files (_small_ files but still _files_)

Comment: An MRE need not be a runnable code snippet. You can have multiple code blocks in a post (surround your code with triple backticks `\`\`\``). Note that a codepen link is not acceptable as a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @SecurityHound there could be cases where some behaviour arises when you have two files and isn't present when you have just one file. So, multiple files can very much be the most minimal example one can show.

Comment: Possibly related to MREs having multiple/large files: [How are we supposed to provide large source files that cannot be reduced?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309256/2821954), [What should a 'minimal, reproducible example' include for problems with automating web browsers using Selenium?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405791/2821954), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example for C# UI related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/340798/2821954).

Comment: Another point of MRE is to help the asker in dividing and conquering the issue until it is small enough to be reproducible... and hopefully, the asker also finds the cause and the solution in the process.

Answer (score 20):

> Is referencing Codepen and similar sites acceptable in these kinds of situations

Questions should be *self-contained*. Any links in the question should be supplementary, the question should *not* rely on visiting the link. The off-site resource may change, or be inaccessible for any reason*.

Add any relevant code to the question. If there are multiple files, add them to the question as different code blocks

###### first_file.xyz

```
// content of first file
```

###### second_file.xyz

```
// content of second file
```

And so on.

**Very important to stress**: make sure that the multiple files are indeed needed. Because one of the key parts of a good example is being minimal. Only include the code needed. And if having multiple files is irrelevant, then combine them into a single code block or (if possible) a runnable snippet.

---

* <sup>On a personal note, Codepen does not work for me because of some addons I have on my browser. And I frankly cannot be bothered to fiddle around to make it work because I never really use it. If that is the only way to see the code, I will pass.</sup>

Comment: Re *"make sure that the multiple files are indeed needed"*: That can be read the wrong way.

Answer (score 11):

The defacto response is that multiple files isn't "minimal", but I wanted to think about this a bit differently.

What we really care about is that there's *just* enough code to reproduce your specific problem.  Your role as an asker should be to trim down the question you're asking to only contain the essentials which - by itself - has enough info to determine what your specific problem is.

If you *have* to have multiple files (like you're building a website snippet, for instance), you should be sure that there's enough snippets to comprise the whole problem (HTML, CSS, JS/TS).  If not, omit where necessary just to narrow your scope.

Answer (score 6):

Since there seems to be some ongoing confusion on this point in your more recent Meta, and it does not seem to have been addressed here yet:

> It seems the in-built MRE tool (the one with the "Run this code snippet" button)

This ***is not*** "the in-built MRE tool".

It is **not necessary** for **any** question to use this feature, in order to provide an MRE.

It is *only a convenience* for demonstrating examples in the browser, which works *only for JavaScript/HTML/CSS examples* (because that is what the browser environment supports out-of-box).

---

To reiterate: the code for an MRE, regardless of language, consists of

- the **contents of source files** needed to cause the problem, with proper formatting;
- **if there is more than one file, some instructions** about how to name them and organize them in the file system.

We should have full **steps to reproduce** - hence, the file names/folder structure, if applicable. The steps to reproduce should be **as simple as possible**: so, hard-code the inputs where you can, and remove parts of the calculation that are not relevant to causing the problem. The idea is that we should be able to **copy and paste** the code into the appropriate files and folder structure, **without adding or changing anything**, and see the **exact problem, directly**.

All of this is already documented [in the site help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Like it says, all emphasis mine:

> Use *individual code blocks for each file* or snippet you include. *Provide a description for the purpose of each block.*... *If you are using HTML, CSS, and/or JavaScript,* you can use Stack Snippets to include [a]runnable snippet instead of just a static code block.

Comment: I also noticed the characterisation *"the in-built [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) tool"* at the time, but is it totally wrong? [The tag wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/stack-snippets/info) says (my emphasis) *"Stack Snippets ... are an onsite alternative to external sources like JSFiddle and are meant to* ***encourage users to provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example*** *along with pertinent questions."*.

Comment: Encourage, not enable.